# Access VBA automation able to save Word document to Sharepoint but not Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, sharepoint, ms-word

I have an Access database that creates files and saves them to Sharepoint on an internal network. In two cases the files are Word documents and saving them to Sharepoint works fine. Two of the files are Excel spreadsheets, and saving them using save or savecopy is not working. The last file is PowerPoint, and saving it is also failing.

The Word save that works looks like this:

```
Set objWord = New Word.Application
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
objWord.Visible = True
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
Set objRange = objDoc.Range

Creation of document

Dim SPAddress As String
SPAddress = GetSPAddress(iProjectId) & "ProjectFactSheet_" & sSiteName & "_" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmddhhnnss") & ".docx"
objDoc.SaveAs SPAddress
```

The Excel save that fails looks like this:

```
Set oExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExcelApp.Visible = True
oExcelApp.AskToUpdateLinks = False
oExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
oExcelApp.Workbooks.Open ("c:\apps\" & strReportName)
SPAddress = GetSPAddress()
oExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs SPAddress & strReportName
```

- savecopyas also gets an error.

This fails with the error filename cannot be accessed. The file may be corrupted, located on a server that is not responding or read only.

```
Public Function GetSPAddress(Optional lngQuaID As Long) As String
    GetSPAddress = ""

    If IsNull(lngQuaID) Or lngQuaID = 0 Then
        GetSPAddress = DLookup("SPBasePath", "AppData")
    Else
        If IsNull(DLookup("[SPPath]", "QualificationLog", "[QuaID] = " & lngQuaID)) Then
            GetSPAddress = DLookup("SPBasePath", "AppData")
        Else
            GetSPAddress = DLookup("[SPPath]", "QualificationLog", "[QuaID] = " & lngQuaID)
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: What is the path used for saving, and how does it compare to the working Word path ?

Comment: The path to the SP folder is the same. Only the file names are different.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link under the question to add the code for `GetSPAddress`. I do notice that for Word you pass a value to this method, but not for the code that's not working?

Comment: If you `Debug.Print` the Excel path can you save to that location manually ?

Comment: Yes, I can save to it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think of to suggest is to set a workbook variable when you open the report so you can be absolutely sure which file is getting saved (though that in itself shouldn't cause an error...)

```
Dim wb As Object   '<<<
Set oExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExcelApp.Visible = True
oExcelApp.AskToUpdateLinks = False
oExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wb = oExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("c:\apps\" & strReportName) '<<<
SPAddress = GetSPAddress()
wb.SaveAs SPAddress & strReportName '<<<
```

Comment: I tried this and I get an error Runtime error '1004'. The file could not be accessed. Try one of the following: Make sure the specified folder exists. ...

Comment: The path being saved to goes to is https:\\eu001-sp.shell.com\sites\AAAAA9233\TestForLIR\Test4.xls

Comment: `https:\\ ` or `https:// ` ?  I was able to run a SaveAs from excel into a Sharepoint library using the same type of path, so it can work...

Comment: Tim made the correct remark. I feel silly, but I was using \ instead of /. As soon as I made that change it worked fine. Thanks!